# Joomla, k2, ajax pagination, SEF wrong address

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla, pagination

I need pagination in K2 content manager work with ajax and i'm using JA Fubix joomla template i send my ajax request in template script.js: (base url is my root path /htdocs/sitefolder/)

```
request = jQuery.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'components/com_k2/admin/loadcontent.php?',
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function(respond) {
                //something
            },
            fail: function() {
                //something
            },
            done: function() {
                //something
            }
        });
```

loadcontent.php is the php file that i made to handle my request. My address for some categories must be like this:

```
http://localhost/1varzesh/persons/philipp-lahm
```

but they have extra "components/com_k2/admin"

```
http://localhost/1varzesh/components/com_k2/admin/persons/philipp-lahm
```

I use K2 route.php file in loadcontent.php. Any idea?

Comment: can i send my request to loadcontent.php with my root address?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on with your code, but have you created a menu item pointing to K2 somewhere in your menu item manager? That could be the problem. Without it, you will have the component/com_k2 part. I'm not sure why you have the "admin" part in the URL.

Comment: my file that handles ajax request is at [root]/components/com_k2/admin/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved with `die();` function. I changed my request from `loadcontent.php` to joomla! `index.php` file (i just left the url blank) and added `die();` after the code i wanted in request. My request delayed about 0.1(s). Thanks to Saeed Mortazavi.